# How do I customize the error message for an ASP.NET Web API GET controller that expects an int parameter but receives a non-int parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

The error message is as follows when I send a Get request to the endpoint that isn't an integer (api/endpoint/abdcdegh when it should be api/endpoint/2)

**{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Get(Int32)' in {CONTROLLER_NAME}. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}**

Is a filter/attribute the best way to customize this / return a custom response? If so, how does one catch this exception with a filter?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use route constraints

```
Route(("~/api/endpoint/{int:id}")
public IActionResult Endpoint(int id)
```

in this case it will return 404 if user using string that cant be converted into integer.

If you want to make a custom error, you can make endpoint parameter a string type, and check if you can parse it to integer. If not, return bad request:

```
Route(("~/api/endpoint/{id?}")
public IActionResult Endpoint(string id)
{
        int number;

         bool success = Int32.TryParse(id, out number);
         if (!success) return BadRequest("Error message");
         
        ..... // the code
         
}
```